# name "plot" is not defined

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot some data using matplotlib with the code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data_x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
data_y = 10 * np.exp(-data_x)
np.savetxt('tabelle1.txt', np.column_stack([data_x, data_y]), header='U I')
x, y = np.genfromtxt('tabelle1', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x, y, 'rx')
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('loesung.pdf')
```

However, this generates an error saying `NameError: name plot is not defined`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show us the full error-message!

Comment: Is this really the **complete error-message* (it still looks incomplete; just show us the complete output)? But it looks you have a problem with your matplotlib installation, because plt.plot should never throw this error.

Answer (score -1):

please try

```
#Add this script
import matplotlib

#Before
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```